# found changes on same id (column A) pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe

```
# |  A    |   B   |   C   |   D   |   E   
--+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------
1 |  "5"  |  "4"  |  "2"  |  "3"  |  "2022-11-29"  |
2 |  "5"  |  "d"  |  "2"  |  "3"  |  "2022-11-30"  |
3 |  "5"  |  "4"  |  "2"  |  "h"  |  "2022-11-29"  |
4 |  "4"  |  "4"  |  "2"  |  "3"  |  "2022-11-28"  |
5 |  "4"  |  "4"  |  "g"  |  "3"  |  "2022-11-29"  |
```

I would like to find changes in same id (column A), but ignore changes in column E

expected result:

```
ID 5 changed in column B (changedTovalue "d") and column D (changedTovalue "h")
ID 4 changed in column C (changedTovalue "g")
```

is this possible to do with pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare most common value per columns by [`DataFrame.mode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mode.html) by [`DataFrame.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html), set missing values by [`DataFrame.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) if no match, reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), last convert to `DataFrame`:

```
df1 = df.set_index('A').drop('E', axis=1)

print (df1)
   B  C  D
A         
5  4  2  3
5  d  2  g <- added new not matched value
5  4  2  h
4  4  2  3
4  4  g  3

s = df1.mode().iloc[0]


df2 = (df1.where(df1.ne(s)).stack()
          .rename_axis(['A','cols'])
          .reset_index(name='val'))
print (df2)
   A cols val
0  5    B   d
1  5    D   g
2  5    D   h
3  4    C   g
```

EDIT:

```
df1 = df.set_index(['A','E'])
print (df1)
              B  C  D
A E                  
5 2022-11-29  4  2  3
  2022-11-30  d  2  3
  2022-11-29  4  2  h
4 2022-11-28  4  2  3
  2022-11-29  4  g  3

s = df1.mode().iloc[0]


df2 = (df1.where(df1.ne(s)).stack()
           .rename_axis(['A','E','cols'])
           .reset_index(name='val')
          )
print (df2)
   A           E cols val
0  5  2022-11-30    B   d
1  5  2022-11-29    D   h
2  4  2022-11-29    C   g
```

Comment: please, but ignore changes in column E?

Comment: @DmitrijHolkin - I use original data

Comment: it possible set index  on multiple columns? it possible drop  on multiple columns?

Comment: @DmitrijHolkin - Sure, is possible multiple not matched values? Or always one?

Comment: @DmitrijHolkin - yes, it is possible - `df1 = df.set_index(['A', 'col1']).drop(['E', 'col2'], axis=1)`

Comment: good, but droped columns should also exists in result as it timestamps :)

Comment: @DmitrijHolkin - Can you be ore specific? Is possible change data in question?

Comment: No, just show droped column in result, as they contain timestamps

Comment: @DmitrijHolkin - Answer was edited.

Comment: What means cols  here  .rename_axis(['A','E','cols']  ? all others columns names?

Comment: @DmitrijHolkin - exactly, columns name which matched.

Comment: Strange things hapeans if i do `df2.to_csv(df2_f, index=False)` all columns saving in new row, how to convert to table? and write to csv same view like in console output?

Comment: @DmitrijHolkin - Do you test it in excel? Or in some text editor like notepad++ ?

Comment: notepad and excel same things all columns transposed

Comment: @DmitrijHolkin - for testing what is ouput `print (df2.to_csv(index=False))` ?

Comment: This ouput is written to csv file

Comment: yep also printed transposed, i have updated post with examples

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250008/discussion-between-jezrael-and-dmitrij-holkin).